# can't install php pusher on mac

Tags: php, macos

i got this error

```
Problem 1
    - pusher/pusher-php-server v2.6.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your sy stem.
    - pusher/pusher-php-server 2.6.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your sys tem.
    - pusher/pusher-php-server 2.6.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your sys tem.
    - pusher/pusher-php-server 2.6.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your sys tem.
    - Installation request for pusher/pusher-php-server ^2.6 -> satisfiable by pusher/pusher-php-server[2.6.1, 2.6.2,
 2.6.3, v2.6.0].
```

when i tried to install pusher for laravel project on on my mac machine (sierra 10.12)

i already add this line on my php.ini file: extension=curl.so
error still the same

Comment: check if curl is really installed. `php -m` from command and `phpinfo()` for web

Comment: @bansi yes curl is installed

Comment: btw I think the ini line should be `extension=php_curl.so`. Which version of PHP are you using?